Why setting "setChunkedStreamingMode" throws Socket Exception?
I'm trying to upload a file to a server using the HttpUrlConnection.
AFAIU, Passing a buffer size to setChunkedStreamingMode, avoids memory exhaustion while transferring large files through HttpUrlConnection. Source of my inference
Below I have provided the shortened version of my code that works while the setChunkedStreamingMode is commented. But uncommenting setChunkedStreamingMode, causes "Socket Exception. Broken pipe"
I'm not sure if I'm using it correct. Can anyone help me in suggesting how to use the setChunkedStreamingMode
Code:
      try{ 
            val dataStream = applicationContext.contentResolver.openInputStream(Uri.parse(fileUri))
            val url = URL(urlString)
            val httpConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
            for (i in keys.indices) {
                httpConnection.setRequestProperty(keys[i], values[i])
            }

            httpConnection.requestMethod = "POST"
            httpConnection.doOutput = true

            // setting the chunked mode. Causing Socket exception. 
            // httpConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE * 2)

            val outPutStream = BufferedOutputStream(httpConnection.outputStream)

            var bytesCopied: Long = 0
            val buffer = ByteArray(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
            var bytes = dataStream.read(buffer)


            while (bytes >= 0 && !isStopped) {
                outPutStream.write(buffer, 0, bytes)
                bytes = dataStream.read(buffer)
            }
     }
     catch(ex){
         print(ex) // Prints Socket exception "Broken pipe" if setChunkedStreamingMode is used
     }


Exception thrown on uncommenting the setChunkedStreamingMode
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe

java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:116)
java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:156)
com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLOutputStream.writeToSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:762)
com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLOutputStream.writeInternal(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:736)
com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLOutputStream.write(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:699)
com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$1.write(Okio.java:78)
com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$1.write(AsyncTimeout.java:157)
com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:177)
com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSink.write(RealBufferedSink.java:47)
com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream$ChunkedSink.write(Http1xStream.java:327)
com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:177)
com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSink$1.write(RealBufferedSink.java:199)
java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
myapp(upload.kt:558)
myapp.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:14)
kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)


You shouldn't exclude the initial exception line output from traces like this. What was the value of "DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE "? Also, what server was it connected to? Not every server supports chunked transfers.

Sorry my bad, I have added the initial exception line.
Regarding the DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE, I used this constant from kotlin.io's ConstantsKt.class
public const val DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE: Int = 8 * 1024
Regarding the server it was connected, It is a private server which I couldn't share here. Thanks for pointing that server support is required. I will check the server side and get back on this. @nitind
